# Unable to simulate a differential wheeled robot with kinematics mode (World file and controller code attached)

Tags: python, webots

According to [the webots documentation](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/physics#how-to-use-physics-nodes), a robot with differential wheels is automatically detected and can be automatically simulated in kinematics model if the physics node is disabled

> The Robot nodes with a differential wheels configuration are a special
> case: they can move even if they don't have Physics nodes. That's
> because Webots uses a special kinematics algorithm for this kind of
> robots without Physics. However, if the Physics nodes are present then
> Webots uses the regular physics simulation algorithms. For a Robot
> node to be detected as a differential wheels, the following
> constraints must be satisfied: the robot must have 2 HingeJoint nodes
> whose axes are aligned and the Solid nodes in the endPoint field of
> the joints must each have a Cylinder node as bounding object with the
> same radius.

I followed the [4-wheeled robot tutorial](https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/tutorial-6-4-wheels-robot?tab-language=python) in webots to build a differential wheel robot, which also satistfies the requirement of:

"*2 HingeJoint nodes whose axes are aligned and the Solid nodes in the endPoint field of the joints must each have a Cylinder node as bounding object with the same radius.*".

The problem is, when I set the physics node of the robot node to be Null and set the wheel velocity to a number, nothing happened. The robot didn't move in the kinematics mode. The body was static and stuck to the ground, but the wheels can rotate. It is as if, the differential wheel configuration was not detected and it wasn't simulated in the kinematics mode. The robot only moved when I added a physics node to the robot node.

Here is my world file

```
#VRML_SIM R2023b utf8

EXTERNPROTO "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2023b/projects/objects/backgrounds/protos/TexturedBackground.proto"
EXTERNPROTO "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2023b/projects/objects/backgrounds/protos/TexturedBackgroundLight.proto"
EXTERNPROTO "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cyberbotics/webots/R2023b/projects/objects/floors/protos/Floor.proto"

WorldInfo {
}
Viewpoint {
  orientation -0.23624887082405407 -0.25731267314299494 0.9370040871172151 4.703178361918595
  position -0.1539983359533472 1.0967505598498564 0.6370930656503582
}
TexturedBackground {
}
TexturedBackgroundLight {
}
Floor {
  translation 0 0 -0.1
  size 1 1
}
Solid {
  translation 0 -0.5 -0.05
  rotation 0 1 0 4.692820414042842e-06
  children [
    DEF WALL_SHAPE Shape {
      appearance PBRAppearance {
        baseColorMap ImageTexture {
          url [
            "red_brick_wall.jpg"
          ]
        }
      }
      geometry Box {
        size 1 0.01 0.1
      }
    }
  ]
  name "Wall1"
  boundingObject USE WALL_SHAPE
}
Solid {
  translation -0.5 0 -0.05
  rotation 0 0 1 1.5708
  children [
    USE WALL_SHAPE
  ]
  name "Wall2"
  boundingObject USE WALL_SHAPE
}
Solid {
  translation 0 0.5 -0.05
  rotation 0 0 1 -3.1415853071795863
  children [
    USE WALL_SHAPE
  ]
  name "Wall3"
  boundingObject USE WALL_SHAPE
}
Solid {
  translation 0.5 0 -0.05
  rotation 0 0 1 1.5708
  children [
    USE WALL_SHAPE
  ]
  name "Wall4"
  boundingObject USE WALL_SHAPE
}
Robot {
  translation 0 0 -0.06
  children [
    DEF BODY Shape {
      appearance PBRAppearance {
        baseColor 1 0 0
        roughness 1
        metalness 0
      }
      geometry Box {
        size 0.2 0.1 0.05
      }
    }
    HingeJoint {
      jointParameters HingeJointParameters {
        axis 0 1 0
        anchor 0.05 0.06 0
      }
      device [
        RotationalMotor {
          name "wheel1"
          acceleration 1
        }
      ]
      endPoint DEF WHEEL1 Solid {
        translation 0.05 0.06 0
        rotation 1 0 0 1.5708
        children [
          DEF WHEEL Shape {
            appearance PBRAppearance {
              baseColor 0 1 0
              roughness 1
              metalness 0
            }
            geometry Cylinder {
              height 0.02
              radius 0.04
            }
          }
        ]
        boundingObject USE WHEEL
      }
    }
    HingeJoint {
      jointParameters HingeJointParameters {
        axis 0 1 0
        anchor 0.05 -0.06 0
      }
      device [
        RotationalMotor {
          name "wheel2"
          acceleration 1
        }
      ]
      endPoint DEF WHEEL2 Solid {
        translation 0.05 -0.06 0
        rotation 1 0 0 1.5708
        children [
          USE WHEEL
        ]
        name "solid2"
        boundingObject USE WHEEL
      }
    }
    HingeJoint {
      jointParameters HingeJointParameters {
        axis 0 1 0
        anchor -0.05 0.06 0
      }
      device [
        RotationalMotor {
          name "wheel3"
          acceleration 1
        }
      ]
      endPoint DEF WHEEL3 Solid {
        translation -0.05 0.06 0
        rotation 1 0 0 1.5708
        children [
          USE WHEEL
        ]
        name "solid3"
        boundingObject USE WHEEL
      }
    }
    HingeJoint {
      jointParameters HingeJointParameters {
        axis 0 1 0
        anchor -0.05 -0.06 0
      }
      device [
        RotationalMotor {
          name "wheel4"
          acceleration 1
        }
      ]
      endPoint DEF WHEEL4 Solid {
        translation -0.05 -0.06 0
        rotation 1 0 0 1.5708
        children [
          USE WHEEL
        ]
        name "solid4"
        boundingObject USE WHEEL
      }
    }
  ]
  boundingObject USE BODY
  controller "obstacle_avoidance"
}
```

and My controller in python to test if the robot can move when the physics node is disabled

```
from controller import Robot

TIME_STEP = 64
robot = Robot()

wheels = []
wheelsNames = ['wheel1', 'wheel2', 'wheel3', 'wheel4']
for i in range(4):
    wheels.append(robot.getDevice(wheelsNames[i]))
    wheels[i].setPosition(float('inf'))
    wheels[i].setVelocity(0.0)
avoidObstacleCounter = 0
while robot.step(TIME_STEP) != -1:
    leftSpeed = 1.0
    rightSpeed = 1.0

    wheels[0].setVelocity(leftSpeed)
    wheels[1].setVelocity(rightSpeed)
    wheels[2].setVelocity(leftSpeed)
    wheels[3].setVelocity(rightSpeed)
```